# No Project Shown - Google Developers Console

Tags: google-play

I have been assigned to a project in Google Developers Console. I have logged in before, seen the project, made changes and saved successfully several times.

Now, the project is no longer listed. Others on project can see it, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you are logged into the same Google account you got the project assigned to?

Comment: Yes. I had this problem the other day and the admin removed me from the project and re-invited me. When connecting right from the invite, I could see the project and manage. Any subsequent logins and the project doesnt show

Comment: That's odd. I have no idea what it could be, other than that your are logged into two accounts at the same time. Can be worth a try to log out from all accounts again and try the one you know is the right one.
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?elo=1

Comment: No luck. Signed completely out, tried again. Used a different browser, tried in incognito mode. Ensured all other Google accounts were not logged in.

Comment: Are you logging in to the right console? There is one for the Google Play (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) and the regular Developer console (https://console.developers.google.com/project)

Comment: I think that was it! Thank you for the quick help. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help. I'll post an answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not logging in to the right console. There is one for the [Google Play](http://play.google.com/apps/publish) and the regular [Developer Console](http://console.developers.google.com/project).